# Setting PS1 from command output

Tags: bash, prompt

I'm attempting to set my bash prompt string from a gsettings value like below.

```
PS1=$(gsettings get org.gnome.finalterm status-bar-left)
```

`gsettings get org.gnome.finalterm status-bar-left` outputs `'\w'`

but in my prompt string it is not expanded and I get a literal `'\w'` instead of the current working directory.

How can I get bash to expand the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash expects its PS1 value in quotes:

```
PS1="$(gsettings get org.gnome.finalterm status-bar-left)"
```